# Tree TableView with multiple NSMutablearray

Tags: ios, uitableview, treeview, nsmutablearray, didselectrowatindexpath

I am try to make tree table like shopping app(main name,category name and sub category name) but not getting proper.i am using `NSMutableArray`

please help me.

example Like ::: Laptop (main name) ,Company (Category Name),Model (Sub Category Name)

My response like : https://github.com/seletz/CocoaTreeViewExample

Comment: i am add name in header and category in table row but when click on catoegory show sub category thats my main problem (i add my code but my code and responce big so i dont add) plz check on https://github.com/seletz/CocoaTreeViewExample same responce from my side

Comment: @priyapatel, Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this link for creating tree based table :
http://sugartin.info/2011/07/20/447/